# Removing Documents from collections using complex queries on C# Driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

In The MongoDB C# driver you can remove a set of documents based on a query like this:

```
collection.Remove(Query<Entity>.EQ(e => e.parentId, parentId));
```

what if I want to remove documents based on a more complex query? i.e.

```
(e.parentId == parentId && e.count > 60)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `QueryBuilder` to build complex queries:

```
var builder = new QueryBuilder<Entity>();
collection.Remove(
    builder.And(
        builder.EQ(_ => _.parentId, parentId),
        builder.EQ(_ => _.count, 60)));
```